# Space between '+' and '=' in the operator +=

Tags: c++, c

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
   int iTemp = 0;

   iTemp += 1;     // Valid

   iTemp + = 1;   // This gives an error ( note the space between '+' and '=')

   return 0;
}
```

Should the parser not automatically have consumed this space and checked for the presence of  '=' as '+=' is also a valid token, rather than throwing an error ?

Similarly I get an error for doing  <  iostream  >

Can someone please explain.

Comment: this is assigning 1 to both `iTemp` and ` ` and the compiler doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: Do you think `int imidate(10);` and `intimidate(10);` should be the same thing?

Comment: I wonder what you would expect the compiler to do for `+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + `

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Print the latest stock values from the Nasdaq?

Comment: What they said. You may be confused with other languages where things like that can have spaces in them. Pascal for instance, where `if a> =b then c: =3` is valid.

Comment: @kerrek sb Thanks! that rang some bells..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't work.
The first step of C compilation is tokenization - breaking the sequence of characters to separate language elements. For example:
`int x=333;` becomes the list `int`, `x`, `=`, `333` and `;`'.
Once this is done, the compiler can figure out which token means what and how to combine them.

If tokenization sees the sequence `+=`, it generates one token. If it sees a space, it generates two: `+` and `=`.

Comment: +1 for expressing the first basic step of any compiler. When you get to know how it works, you are less mystified by the errors... (although some would argue that then you get less wild ideas)

Comment: Consider this case now: `#include < iostream >` As per your explanation it will get tokenized into  - `#`,`include`,`<`,`iostream`,`>`and should not produce any error !?

Comment: I think `# include < iostream >` (with spaces all over) is valid. However, preprocessing is done before compilation, and behaves somewhat differently (e.g. you can use it to paste `+` with `=` getting `+=`).

Comment: @ugoren I clearly understood your explanation about tokenization of += operator. Can you please explain a bit more about what you meant by `preprocessing behaves somewhat differently (e.g. you can use it to paste + with = getting += )`

Comment: First, the preprocessor is separate from the compiler. I.e. it tokenizes, does its thing, writes the file, then the compiler starts tokenizing again. Also, in the preprocessor, a token may be created from other tokens. If you `#define A(x,y) x##y` then `A(+,=)` becomes the `+=` token. And if you `#define xx yy`, then `A(x,x)` becomes `xx` and then `yy`.

Answer (score 12):

No, the parser should not have. The specification of the language calls for this behavior, and that's the end of the story.

Comment: Cause for non inclusion of iostream in this is same too(language specification)? `#include < iostream >`

Comment: iostreams were invented many years later than the basic lexical rules of C, and to solve a different problem. There's essentially no relationship.

Comment: What I asked is, this works fine `#include <iostream>`. But this doesn't `#include  < iostream >` (note the spaces) !?

Answer (score 4):

No it should not. The parser is very good but doesn't read minds. It cannot know if either the plus or equals is an error or if the spacing is an error. In any case, the whole thing is an error.

Answer (score 4):

No. `+=` is a single token. `+` and `=` are also single tokens respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The specifications specifies a `+=` operator and not a `+ =` one. So the answer is no. `while` keyword can't be replaced by `whi le`, it's the same for +=

Answer (score 3):

I remember, back in the dark ages, when the `op=` tokens had alternative variants `=op`. So `x =+ 5` meant the same as `x += 5`. This was disastrous, of course, because `x=-5` meant `x -= 5` instead of `x = -5`. But even at that early date, these compound tokens were not allowed to contain white space.

Answer (score 3):

+,= and += are different operators. So if you give whitespace between + and =, scanner would tokenise these operators as different operators. And as a result, Syntax Analyzer(Parser) will give a syntax error.

Comment: How about this? `#include < iostream >` . I get an error in this, though it will get properly tokenized into  `#`,`include`, `<`, `iostream`, `>` !?

Answer (score 0):

Why would it work?
If you try to increment `a = a+ +` it won't work either.